# ¿Cómo renderizar una vista apropiadamente?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una vista desde la cual necesito renderizar a otra el problema es que no se hace correctamente por que no pasan los estados.

aqui tengo el link que me debe redirigir el cual esta dentro de una tabla

```
<td><a onClick={this.returnView.bind(this, index)} href="#" className="text-main" idres={item.iddef_group} data-idres={item.iddef_group}>{this.state.lng["0"]["Reservations"]["tblReservaciones"]["0"]["sDetail"]}</a></td>
```

Tengo la funcion con la que seteo estados

```
 returnView(index, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            convertStatus: 1, info: this
                .state
                .datas[index],
                idres: e.target.dataset.idres,
                redirect : true
        });
    }
```

Y en el render quiero redirigir de la siguiente forma

```
 if (this.state.redirect == true) {
            return(
                <div className="container">
                    {console.log("INFO=>",this.state.info)}
                    {console.log("IDRES=>",this.state.idres)}
                    {console.log("LNG=>",this.state.lng)}
                    <Redirect push to="/ReservationDetailMain" component={<Detail data={this.state.info}  idres={this.state.idres} lng={this.state.lng}></Detail>} />
                </div>
            );
        }
```

Se que no esta bien ya que no funciona espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que estas usando *react-router-dom* por el `<Redirect />`

Lo que te está pasando es que al hacer

```
component={<Detail data={this.state.info}  idres={this.state.idres} lng={this.state.lng}></Detail>}
```

Se estan perdiendo las props propias de la navegación. Lo que te recomiendo hacer es cambiarlo a:

```
<Redirect
    to={{
        pathname: "/ReservationDetailMain",
        state: { // aca poner todas las props que queres que reciba el otro componente }
    }}
 />
```

Desde el componente `<Detail />` podes acceder a las props que les mandaste mediante:

```
this.props.location.state // si es una clase
props.location.state // si es una función
```

¡Espero haberte ayudado!